Ruby gems update but old versions still present
I am trying to update rexml to 3.3.9. I updated the version in the Gemfile and run
bundle update rexml

I then ran
gem list | grep rexml
rexml (3.3.9)

and checked the version running in the application
ruby -e "require 'rexml/document'; puts REXML::VERSION"

which also gave me 3.3.9
However in AWS security hub the CVE is still being found in this path.
...3.3.0/gems/rbs-3.4.0/Gemfile.lock

I tried un-pinning all gem versions and running bundle install to regenerate the .lock with all gems updated, but the old version of rexml is still there. I'm new to ruby and having to update and manage dependencies, can anyone explain why I can still see the old version installed in that path? Is it because rbs version has a dependency on the old version of rexml? And if so do I just have to accept that the old version is there?
And is any CVE associated with older versions exploitable if the application is using 3.3.9 at runtime?

that Gemfile is only used during development of the gem, you're not using it in any way. user dependencies are declared in .gemspec files.

It looks like rexml is a dependency of the rbs gem which is forcing rexml to stay the same. Try updating the rbs gem instead.
I'm not familiar with AWS security hub and it's CVE so I'm not sure about that

I have no idea what the OP is trying to communicate but rexml is not a dependency of rbs. The only stated dependency of rbs-3.4.0 is the abbrev gem. Source and that gem has no dependencies.
